# Should Hyperledger Fabric be with a host in DMZ

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm seting up a production environment of Hyperldger Fabric 1.4 and one of my concerns is connectivity with third party systems. Since the infrastructure is not running inside a VPN and third party systems available to public are generating load for our network, I am skeptical about allowing for a connection over public network directly into Hyperledger Composer API. I am wondering if anybody has experience with performance when deploying a intermediary host that is solely allowed to communicate with Hyperledger network?

Answer (score 0):

Don't see a problem with that, if you need that kind of setup. If you use composer you will have an API to communicate with your network. Nothing stops you from creating another app that solely communicates with this API.

The performance depends on other factors, like number of requests, size of data, frequency of data.

Also, don't forget that the Hyperledger API needs to be secured. As for public access, there should be any, the whole point of Hyperledger is to allow only known entities to connect and do whatever needs to be done.